# Where Throws an Incorrect Syntax Adding Variables & "ands" - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with my code:

I'm trying to create a dynamic Pivot to put the information on a Grid of a Local framework.  It works perfectly except when I try to filter the Grid.  How do I create a filter to easily incorporate into a where clause at the end of my Select query?

I do all my queries on a SP and it returns only the information in order just to fill the Grid.

I will try to explain my code. First, I create a temp table that I use to fill the Grid.

```
Create table #tmpColadasLineas (
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),       
Fecha Datetime,
ClaHorno INT,
NoColada INT,
ClaMCC INT,
GradoObtenido Varchar(50),
Seccion varchar(50),
--Resultado
Resultado Varchar(50),
[11] NUMERIC(18,8),
[12]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[13]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[14]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[15]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[16]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[17]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[18]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[21]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[22]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[23]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[24]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[25]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[26]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[27]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[28]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[31]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[32]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[33]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[34]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[35]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[36]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[37]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[38]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[41]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[42]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[43]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[44]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[45]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[46]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[47]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[48]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[51]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[52]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[53]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[54]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[55]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[56]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[57]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[58]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[61]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[62]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[63]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[64]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[65]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[66]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[67]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[68]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[71]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[72]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[73]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[74]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[75]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[76]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[77]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[78]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[81]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[82]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[83]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[84]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[85]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[86]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[87]    NUMERIC(18,8),
[88]    NUMERIC(18,8)
);
```

Then I initialize all my variables for the Pivot function and for the Filter:

```
SELECT @pnHorno = NULLIF(@pnHorno, -1), @pnGrado = NULLIF(@pnGrado, -1)
            , @pdFechaFin = CASE WHEN @pdFechaFin IS NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,@pdFechaInicio) ELSE DATEADD(DAY,1,@pdFechaFin) END

        IF @pnColada IS NOT NULL
        Begin
            select @pdFechaInicio = null, @pdFechaFin = null, @pnHorno = null, @pnGrado = null;
        end
        /*Inicio Pivot*/
        DECLARE
            @Lineas AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @Caracteristicas AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @queryInsert AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @clauseWhere AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

Then I do all the remaining work for the SP to create the pivot:

```
Select @Lineas = STUFF(
            (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(ClaCaracteristicaMacroataque as varchar)+cast(ClaLinea as varchar),'[')
                from ACESch.AceTraMacroataqueDetVw MD
                Group by ClaCaracteristicaMacroataque,ClaLinea Order By ClaCaracteristicaMacroataque,ClaLinea  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                ,1
                ,1 
                ,''
            );
        set @query = 'SELECT 
            --into ##tmpColadasLineas
            fecha_administrativa AS Fecha,ClaHorno As ClaHorno, IdColada As NoColada,cla_mcc AS ClaMCC,cla_grado_obtenido AS GradoObtenido,Seccion,ClaResultadoMacroataque AS Resultado,' + @Lineas + ' from 
            (
                select C.fecha_administrativa,MD.ClaHorno,MD.IdColada,CC.cla_mcc,C.cla_grado_obtenido,Seccion=170,TM.ClaResultadoMacroataque,Valor,CAST(ClaCaracteristicaMacroataque AS VARCHAR(10) )+CAST(ClaLinea AS VARCHAR(10) )  AS CL
                from ACESch.AceTraMacroataqueDetVw MD 
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Pro_Colada C ON MD.IdColada=C.cla_colada
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Pro_Tot_Cc CC ON C.cla_horno = CC.cla_horno AND C.cla_colada = CC.cla_colada
                LEFT JOIN ACESch.AceTraMacroataqueVw TM ON C.cla_colada = TM.IdColada
                WHERE  C.fecha_administrativa >= ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaInicio, 120) + '''  AND C.fecha_administrativa < ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaFin, 120) + ''' 
                or ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaInicio, 120) + '''  is null and ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaFin, 120) + '''  is null 
                or ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaFin, 120) + '''  is null and C.fecha_administrativa >= ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaInicio, 120) + '''
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
               sum(Valor)
               for CL in (' + @Lineas + ')
            ) p
            '
            set @queryInsert = 'insert into #tmpColadasLineas (Fecha, ClaHorno,NoColada,ClaMCC,GradoObtenido,Seccion,Resultado,' + @Lineas + ')'
        truncate table #tmpColadasLineas
        insert into #tmpColadasLineas 
        execute (@queryInsert+@query)   
        Select * from #tmpColadasLineas
```

The bug that is driving me crazy is the WHERE clause.  When I put in all the filters, it produces the following error:

> **Must declare the scalar variable "@pnColada". ( )**

When I try to convert it, gives me this error no matter what I change:

> **Incorrect syntax near ')'. ( )**

Here is the full filter:

```
C.fecha_administrativa >= ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaInicio, 120) + '''  AND C.fecha_administrativa < ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaFin, 120) + ''' 
                    or ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaInicio, 120) + '''  is null and ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaFin, 120) + '''  is null 
                    or ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaFin, 120) + '''  is null and C.fecha_administrativa >= ''' + convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaInicio, 120) + '''
AND (C.cla_horno = @pnHorno OR @pnHorno IS NULL) 
AND (C.cla_grado_obtenido = @pnGrado OR @pnGrado IS NULL)
AND (C.cla_colada = @pnColada OR @pnColada IS NULL)
```

Thanks for you help.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: wow that is a lot to try and get through....have you tried printing your @query variable and copying it into ssms window to toubleshoot the syntax issue?  It will probably become evident to you a bit faster.  Also you could paste the contents of it to your question and we will be able to tell you the problem faster

Comment: That is a lot to look through but you should just convert your variable before the dynamic sql, then concat it into your dynamic sql with ''' + @var '''

Comment: It looks as though @pnColada is a parameter and hasn't been declared.  Might be worth checking the variable declaration section of your stored procedure

Comment: Sorry, "@pdFechaInicio", "@pdFechaFin", "@pnHorno", "@pnGrado", "@pnColada" are variables that i send to my Store Procedure. So all of them are Declared. 

And @scsimon could you post a link with some explanation or example of that are you saying? 

Thanks all of you guys

Comment: `declare @query varchar(max)
declare @pdFechaFin datetime2
set @pdFechaFin = '2016-08-16 12:21:36'
set @pdFechaFin =  convert(varchar(64), @pdFechaFin, 120)
set @query = 'select column1 from table1 where column1 < ' + @pdFechaFin + 'and column1 >' + @pdFechaFin`

Comment: I do that and it work for a while, when i give a Null parameter then it stop working and throws the "Incorrect syntax near ')'. ( )" bug! But because its filter need to allow Nulls. I will try to fix it, Thank you @scsimon